# Grails domain instance not saving

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a grails domain object that I validate and then save as such:

```
if(foo.hasErrors()) {
   transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
   respond foo.errors, view: 'create'
   return
}

foo.save flush:true, failOnError:true

println(foo)
```

There are no errors given on the save.  But when I call the println, it says my object is unsaved.  However, if I check the database, it has indeed been persisted.  Is there something I can check to tell me why grails is telling me it is unsaved.  The grails version is 3.0.9.

After more testing, it looks like it is related to the way I specify the key in my domain mapping.

```
static mapping = {
    version false
    autoTimestamp false
    id name:'foo_id', generator:'increment'
}
```

If I remove the id field and let Grails handle it by default the object is saved properly.  If I add the id field back, it has the issue described above.  Is there a reason for it?

Comment: Did you debug it or just check by println? Moreover which version of Grails? Is function @Transactional?

Comment: Does the status change after you commit the transaction?

Comment: This is grails 3.0.9 .  The function was @Transactional, but I removed all the transactional pieces and have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't be too concerned about the format of `toString()`. You're calling `save` with `failOnError: true`, so it's safe to assume that an exception would be thrown if persistence fails. If you don't specify this argument, you can check that persistence succeeds like so

```
if (foo.save()) {
  println 'it worked'
} else {
  println 'if failed'
}
```

Comment: I was concerned because I was having issues when updating this part at a later step.  It would attempt to create a new instance rather than update the existing and I thought maybe this was part of the problem.  The save method does indeed return true however.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
foo = foo.save flush:true, failOnError:true

println(foo)
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.